# Java 8 and Eclipse on OS X Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, osx-mavericks, java-8

I want to play a bit with the recently released Java 8 on OS X Mavericks, but have problems configuring the `compiler compliance level` to anything beyond `1.7`.

I tried this with a recent Luna build (4.4.0M6) as well as with Kepler (4.3 SR2), patched with [this](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you probably have to manually tweak the config or properties file. but you may not have to do that anymore, i think eclipse just released a new build today that supports java8 out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it right now. I just re-installed the patch from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/) and now `1.8` is shown as compiler level.

I think while the "About" dialog showed me that the patch was installed, it probably wasn't done properly, because it updated other plugins / the IDE to SR2 at the same time.

Anways, this is solved.

Comment: The link you posted is dead. You can add Java 8 support to an existing Kepler install [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/) or do a new install with Java 8 [here](http://eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php).

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems getting Java SE 8 to work in Eclipse too. I followed the [Instructions in the Eclipse wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) for the Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2) version.

After that, I could choose version 1.8 instead of 1.7, which solved the problem. The instructions seem to link to the same patch you used, though, but maybe you missed something important.