# How can I run Eclipse in OS X with JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-8, eclipse-adt

I have downloaded the ADT bundle from Google to develop Android applications. Also I have installed Java with JDK 8u5 for MacOSX 64 bits. When I try to open Eclipse by clicking over Eclipse icon, it shows a dialog saying it's necessary to install a Java 6 version.

Is it possible to execute Eclipse (and other java applications) with Java 8? If yes, How can I do it?

(I have seen solutions for JDK 7 but not for JDK 8)

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518586/java-8-and-eclipse-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Thanks @mortsahl, I had already seen that question. But in it, it seems the user is already running eclipse, and his problem is in configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [current ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk) is built on Eclipse Keplar base. Eclipse (Keplar), currently, does have built in support for using Java 8 .. but it can be added ([here are directions from Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/)). There are builds of the next Eclipse (Luna) release stream that should have Java 8 "builtin" this week. However, I have not seen any plans to build ADT on top of a pre-release Eclipse (Luna) version. The Android team has typically waited beyond release.

Comment: Ok @Erstwhilelll. Thanks for the clarification, I will wait for it ;)